# Java - Cleaning up lots of if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm writing a little project in Java which is similar to the 2048 game, which is pretty much solely based on array manipulation. I wrote a solution to a problem I had, and it works perfectly, however the code is incredibly messy. If anybody could please help with cleaning it up, maybe by using a different technique or something, it is just lots of if statements.

```
// This bit gets rid of the empty tiles between numbers.
    // Eg {2,2,0,4} becomes {2,2,4,0}.
    for(int i =1; i<row.length; i++) {

        if(row[i-1] == 0)
        {
            row[i-1] = row[i];
            row[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int j=row.length-1; j>=1; j--) {
        if(row[j-1] == 0 ) {
            row[j-1] = row[j];
            row[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    int nonEmpty = 0; // Count the number of non empty tiles
    for(int i=0; i<row.length; i++) {
        if(row[i] != 0)
            nonEmpty++;
    }

    if(nonEmpty == 2) {
        if(row[1] == row[0]) {
            row[0] *= 2;
            row[1] = 0;
        }
    }
    else if(nonEmpty == 3) {
        if(row[1] == row[0]) {
            row[0] *= 2;
            row[1] = row[2];
            row[2] = 0;
        }
        else if(row[2] == row[1]) {
            row[1] *= 2;
            row[2] = 0;
        }
    }
    else if(nonEmpty==4) {
        if(row[1] == row[0]) {
            row[0] *= 2;
            row[1] = 0;

            if(row[2] == row[3]) {
                row[2] *= 2;
                row[3] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(row[2] == row[1]) {
            row[1] *= 2;
            row[2] = row[3];
            row[3] = 0;
        }
        else if(row[3] == row[2]) {
            row[2] *= 2;
            row[3] = 0;
        }

    }

    // Get rid of 0s between numbers again.
for(int i =1; i<row.length; i++) {

        if(row[i-1] == 0)
        {
            row[i-1] = row[i];
            row[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int j=row.length-1; j>=1; j--) {
        if(row[j-1] == 0 ) {
            row[j-1] = row[j];
            row[j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Every if/else if statement here is crucial as it takes care of all situations. I'm not asking for somebody to go through and clean it all up, but if I could just have some pointers or examples that'd be great.

Thanks guys

Comment: Looks fine to me. Doesn't matter how many if/else/conditional statements you have.

Comment: yeah, looks pretty cool for me too

Comment: You could use `swtich()` instead of all the if-else if statements

Comment: as you seem to be iterating over the same arrays, can you combines some of your logic into less `for` loops?

Comment: Have you thought about collections framework in Java. I hope Linked List would solve the problem for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
void set(int indexFrom, int... values) {
    for (int v : values)
        row[indexFrom++] = v;
}
```

And rewrite

```
if(row[1] == row[0]) {
    row[0] *= 2;
    row[1] = row[2];
    row[2] = 0;
}
else if(row[2] == row[1]) {
    row[1] *= 2;
    row[2] = 0;
}
```

to

```
if (row[1] == row[0])
    set(0, row[0] * 2, row[2], 0);
else if (row[2] == row[1])
    set(1, row[1] * 2, 0);
```